# Synapse Application search bar indicator?

Tags: unity, indicator, shortcuts, search

I would like to synapse search bar indicator on ubuntu 16.04.
I am using the following command, but its not working:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse
```

And

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gotwig/weekly
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/unstable-upstream
sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse
```

[image]

Comment: in later versions: `sudo apt install synapse` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command on your terminal. Then It will be OK.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse
```

Then follow the following instruction:

**System Settings > Software & Updates > Other Software** > find and click noobslab/apps repository > Edit > change Distrbution value to "trusty". Then `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse`. That's all.

Source: https://gist.github.com/brenopolanski/cb56125da4fede7a8abf